# SRAM BB30 cranks - how to remove crankarm from spindle?

Tags: crankset, repair, bottom-bracket, sram, bb30

I have SRAM S2200 (X.0) cranks with a BB30/PF30 spindle. They are 3-piece ones, with the self-extracting mechanism on the right (drive) side, and a regular non-puller bolt on the left side.

I want to [replace the spindle](https://www.stagescycling.eu/power-meter/accessories/Stages-Spindle-for-SRAM-BB30-SRAM-DUB-Easton-Race-Face-BB30-Specialized.html), because I stripped the thread on the original one. However, I had no luck taking the **left** crankarm off it. The lobed interface between the arm and spindle is fused tight.

Attempts so far:

- WD-40 won't get in there (or has no effect)
- I haven't found a safe way to heat up the crankarm to loosen the join (crankarm is carbon = not a good idea)
- I can't use the self-extracting mechanism from the right side (because there is no thread for the top cap, see pic).
- Hammering on the tightening nut (while it is loosened and slightly protruding above the crank) doesn't seem to do the trick, at some point the hammer just starts to damage the nut itself.

I found [a thread on MTBR](https://forums.mtbr.com/fat-bikes/xx1-crank-next-sl-spindle-922785.html) where somebody accomplished it, but the author hasn't described how (in much detail).

**Any ideas on how to take this thing apart?**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

P.S. The photos might be misleading, so I'll re-emphasize: i only need to take the **left** crankarm off the spindle, i.e. the one which **doesn't** have the self-extracting mechanism. The right crankarm I have no issues with.

Comment: The only comment I saw about taking it off, on the mtbr site was, "Not pressed on the bb30.i had to use alot of force to screw it off, and a rubber mallet to punch out the spindle". But where and how you want to apply that force could be key!

Comment: I have the same issue today, did you manage taking the left crankarm off the spindle ? How ?

Comment: I did, but it was a waste of time, because I couldn't find the right spindle anyway.

With enough torque, you'll loosen the cap, then you can dislodge the crank from the spindle by hammering on the (slightly unscrewed) cap with a rubber mallet. It took a lot of force in my case. Also, make sure that when hammering, you're holding the actual crank and not the spindle. (Duh.)

It's an ugly job that breaks warranty... you've been warned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left arm has no threads because that side is designed never to be separated from the spindle...

From what I can find, that's an M18 thread, pitch unknown but probably M18x2.0mm or M18x1.5mm.

Remove the right arm, put the spindle down through a sturdy surface with a hole no larger than 31mm so the metal part of the left arm has maximum support. Screw a steel rod of the correct M18 threads into the good threads you still have in the spindle. Hammer the end of the rod. The longer the rod the easier it will be to keep it perpendicular to the surface that's supporting the crank.

You can use a deadblow hammer if you have one, or go find an auto mechanic's workshop since they are very likely to have a hydraulic press they use to press bearings into car spindles.