# SRAM S2200 - replacement BB30 spindle?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, sram, bb30

I'm having a hard time finding a replacement BB30 spindle for a SRAM S-2200 (X.0) crankset (originally fitted to a 2013 Specialized Enduro). I stripped the thread on the spindle, but I would like to keep the crankarms (since they are carbon and there's nothing wrong with them.)

I know of 3 manufacturers which make those spindles - Cannondale, RaceFace and Stages - but Cannondale and RaceFace don't make the right length for me and the Stages one doesn't conform to the standard (the angle of the lobed interfaces on the sides of the spindle is mis-aligned by one half-phase, or 22.5 degrees = cranks wouldn't be parallel).

For the record, my BB shell is 73 mm wide and the length of the spindle itself is 114.3 mm (outer edge to outer edge). The crankset uses a 9 mm drive-side spacer between the bearing and the crank.

In case the spindle itself (as a replacement part) is nonexistent, could somebody recommend an entire replacement crankset that is still purchaseable nowadays? (I'm somewhat lost in the whole DUB thing from SRAM...)

(FTR, related question including pics: [SRAM BB30 cranks - how to remove crankarm from spindle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/69607/22612))

Comment: Is this crankset actually modular? To my knowledge, most cranksets have the spindle bonded to one of the arms, and it's not possible for the average consumer to disbond it and rebond a new spindle, if you could even source the correct spindle. I know that Rotor makes completely modular cranksets, where you could replace the spindle separately. If the spindle is bonded, it's possible that people might sell single arms on eBay - probably they damaged the other arm. It's possible that SRAM made single arms available, and maybe someone has old stock somewhere.

Comment: Is it the end of the world for you to use the 119mm cannondale spindle? It's 2.5mm extra spacers each side. Or to use the 109mm and hope you can get a good fit after removing the plastic play-remover (use wavy washer instead) and certain other spacers? It sounds like you have room to play with if the frame can take the slightly reduced Q.

Comment: @WeiwenNg - it is. (Also see linked answer.)

SRAM wrote "do not remove" on the non-drive side nut, yet the lobed interface on the spindle is the same on both sides and the only difference is that the self-extracting mechanism is only on the right crank. So it's possible to separate it into spindle + two crankarms when necessary (as it is in my case).

Comment: @JoeK - as for Cannondale 119mm, I'm concerned about the chainline. I jury-rigged a 1x10 drivetrain (originally 2x10) and I don't know how much abuse the chain can take with that kind of crossing. (Plus, I mixed a SRAM chain and Shi casette...) So I'm afraid what effect moving the chainring further out would have on the chain and largest casette cog. (And I can't move the chainring back towards the center because it's a direct mount.)

Comment: The 109mm is not an option, I already get tons of shoe rub on the seat stays from my big feet :) But the 119mm could actually work, on second thoughts. But I'll have to create some custom spacers underneath the chainring, in addition to the regular 2.5mm spacers on the axle.

Comment: Do you already have a 6mm offset ring, so doing the 119 and then going to the next higher offset for your dm ring isn't an option?

Comment: Also, in theory FSA makes 30mm hexolobular spindles for their modular cranks. I went looking for them but didn't see any available to buy though.

Comment: @zire you can adjust chainline on normal rings with washers so don't see that as a problem. TA even provide these with their ONE rings for fine chainline adjustment

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this issue seems practically unsolvable. My replacement spindle is a niche item that very few manufacturers produce (none in exactly matching length) and almost no bike shop stocks, at least in the EU.

(For the record, I add one more manufacturer to the list: [Leonardi Factory](https://leonardistore.com/collections/crankset/products/41-bb30-bb92-axle). But they seem to have gone out of business.)

I'm left with no other option than to buy a completely new crankset...

Comment: Or a used one that has a good spindle?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed remove the screw from non-drive side but seems the crank arm and spindle are bonded. It is metal to metal where they join.  I do have a s2200 spindle since the carbon part of the crankarm broke away.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Are you answering the original question or offering a spindle?